# Is it possible to use an alternate CD as LiveCD?

Tags: live-cd

I've used the alternate CD for installing my system. When I boot from the CD, I do not see a "Live" option as in the Desktop CD. Do I really need this desktop CD for a Live session, or is it possible with the Alternate CD as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the alternate CD is not a live CD

Comment: Can you provide a source? I don't see a Live option in the menu, but just want to be sure that it's not hidden behind some command or shortcut.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: I found no reference in official docs, only in community docs: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

Comment: "Avoid the "Alternate Cd" & the Server Edition because it has no desktop.", I'll take this as the answer then. Thanks!

Comment: I was referring to: "Almost any Ubuntu Cd can also be used as a LiveCd as well as an installer. It is the default option when booting from Cd. Only some of the non-standard downloads (such as the "Alternate Cd") lack this functionality."

Answer (score 0):

No, The Alternative cd - is useful for low end, or other problem systems. It does not work as a Live Desktop.  It can work as a upgrade cd, which can be a handy feature. You could use its console to do some repairs also.

Comment: Actually, the alternate CD is use for customized installations. I don't think that a system with full-disk encryption is a "problem system" unless the FBI encounters it ;)